# External path Properties file in spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

1.spring-servlet.xml -
`<context:property-placeholder location="local path of database properties file/database.properties"/>`

if i put absolute path in above then i can access the file.
but my absolute path is in general.properties and
general.properties is in my class path

2.general.properties -
`proPath=D:\\Propertiesfile`

so how can i put database.properties file path in spring-servlet.xml

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the Spring Resource abstraction. By default if a resource is not qualified with a handler prefix e.g classpath: file: etc Spring determines the type of resource to load based on the type of ApplicationContext used.

If its a ClassPathXmlApplicationContext it uses a classpath resource. If its a FileSystemXmlApplicationContext it uses a file system resource. If its a web application context it uses Servlet context resource. However you can force it to load a specific type irregardless of application context type by appending the handler prefix e.g classpath:database.properties which loads your file from the classpath

You can use `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties"/>` if your database.properties is in the classpath

Or `<context:property-placeholder location="database.properties"/>` if your database.properties is in the root of the web application

Comment: thanks Ekem for your answer,actually i have already applied your suggestion, but i have to load properties file from path which is in general.properties,so i want to know how can i put relative path in spring-servlet.xml which will refer to general.properties and thus indirectly refer to database.properties file.